How to rewrite the last prefix (/index.html) at the end of url in Istio VirtualService?
I need to get rid of index.html at the end of url, so
https://somehost/somepath/index.html
is rewritten to
https://somehost/somepath
I tried
  - match:
    - uri:
        regex: (.*)\/index.html
    route:
    - destination:
        host: allure-service-clusterip.allure-docker-service.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 7070
    rewrite:
      uriRegexRewrite:
        match: (.*)\/index.html
        rewrite: /\1

and
- match:
  - uri:
      prefix: /index.html
  route:
  - destination:
      host: allure-service-clusterip.allure-docker-service.svc.cluster.local
      port:
        number: 7070
  rewrite:
      uri: /

but it does not work.
Originally it was implemented with nginx ingress as following:
https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service-examples/blob/master/allure-docker-kubernetes-example/allure-ingress-service-load-balancer.yml
Any ideas?

To get rid of index.html at the end of your URL using Istio Virtual Service, you can use the rewrite field with a regular expression. Here's a config that should do the trick:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: allure-virtual-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - your-gateway-name
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        regex: ^(.*/)index.html$
    rewrite:
      uri: "$1"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: allure-service-clusterip.allure-docker-service.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 7070

Here's what's going on:

The ﻿match section uses a regular expression ﻿^(./)index.html$ to
match URLs that end with ﻿/index.html. The ﻿(.) captures the path
before ﻿/index.html.

The ﻿rewrite section rewrites the URI using the
captured group from the match. The ﻿uri field is set to ﻿"$1", which
replaces the matched URI with the captured path, effectively
removing ﻿/index.html from the end.

The ﻿route section specifies
where the request should be sent, which is the
﻿allure-service-clusterip service in the ﻿allure-docker-service
namespace.


Don't forget to replace ﻿your-gateway-name with the actual name of your Istio Gateway.
With this setup, requests to ﻿https://somehost/somepath/index.html will be rewritten to ﻿https://somehost/somepath and sent to the specified destination service.

Thank you for the answer. But I tried this way and got 400 Bad Request.
curl shows:
`

HEAD /allure-ui/allure-docker-service-ui/projects/exp-test-automation-service/reports/latest/index.html HTTP/2
Host: ***
accept: /


TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
old SSL session ID is stale, removing
Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 2147483647)!

HTTP/2 400
content-length: 11
content-type: text/plain
server: istio-envoy
`
Logs of istio-proxy container of the pod:
"- - HTTP/1.1" 400 DPE http1.codec_error - ...

Thanks for the feedback, I was working off my notes as I went through the same issue a while back. Looks like the API might have changed in newer versions. I will double check and update my answer.
